# Flexible UNIX command line interface with Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I was wondering how to create a flexible CLI interface with Python. So far I have come up with the following:

```
$ cat cat.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import stdin
from fileinput import input
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType

def main(args):

   for line in input():
      print line.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('FILE', nargs='?', type=FileType('r'), default=stdin)
   main(parser.parse_args())
```

This handles both stdin and file input:

```
$ echo 'stdin test' | ./cat.py
stdin test

$ ./cat.py file
file test
```

The problem is it doesn't handle multiple input or no input the way I would like:

```
$ ./cat.py file file
usage: cat.py [-h] [FILE]
cat.py: error: unrecognized arguments: file

$ ./cat.py
```

For multiple inputs it should `cat` the file multiple times and for no input input should ideally have same the behaviour as `-h`:

```
$ ./cat.py -h
usage: cat.py [-h] [FILE]

positional arguments:
  FILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Any ideas on creating a flexible CLI interface with Python?

Comment: Why are you using both `fileinput` and `argparse`?  `input()` does: `"This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty."`  Do you realize that `argparse` `FileType` opens the files that you name?  As written you don't do anything with those opened files.

Comment: @hpaulj you are right I should pass the files to `fileinput` see my [answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19281395/1066031)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty good CLI interface the handles file input, standard input, no input, file output and inplace editing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main(args, help):
    '''
    Simple line numbering program to demonstrate CLI interface
    '''

    if not (select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],0.0)[0] or args.files):
        help()
        return

    if args.output and args.output != '-':
        sys.stdout = open(args.output, 'w')

    try:
        for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(args.files, inplace=args.inplace)):
            print i + 1, line.strip()
    except IOError:
        sys.stderr.write("%s: No such file %s\n" % 
                        (os.path.basename(__file__), fileinput.filename()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, sys, select, argparse, fileinput
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*', help='input files')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-i', '--inplace', action='store_true', 
                       help='modify files inplace')
    group.add_argument('-o', '--output', 
                       help='output file. The default is stdout')
    main(parser.parse_args(), parser.print_help)
```

The code simply emulates `nl` and numbers the lines but should serve as a good skeleton for many applications.

Comment: Right, so with no arguments and *no `stdin` pipe attached* you show help, otherwise you read from `stdin`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`nargs='*'`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs) to allow for 0 or more arguments:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('FILE', nargs='*', type=FileType('r'), default=stdin)
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

The help output now is:

```
$ bin/python cat.py -h
usage: cat.py [-h] [FILE [FILE ...]]

positional arguments:
  FILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and when no arguments are given, `stdout` is used.

If you want to require at least one `FILE` argument, use `nargs='+'` instead, but then the default is ignored, so you may as well drop that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('FILE', nargs='+', type=FileType('r'))
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

Now not specifying a command-line argument gives:

```
$ bin/python cat.py
usage: cat.py [-h] FILE [FILE ...]
cat.py: error: too few arguments
```

You can always specify `stdin` still by passing in `-` as an argument:

```
$ echo 'hello world!' | bin/python cat.py -
hello world!
```

Comment: This gets me 90% of the way there +1. Just handling `stdin` without `-` would be perfect.

Comment: @sudo_O: That's handled by the `nargs='*'` and no arguments case; that's how defaults work. How did you envision `stdin` being handled in the `nargs='+'` case? You are then specifically stating there needs to be at least *one* argument.

Comment: Thanks gave me a push in the right direction, [I figured it out in the end](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19281395/1066031)